# Macro matching a single expr after [expr*], path[tt*] and ident[tt*] branches

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to make a macro that I can call in the following manner:

```
mactest!(some::Path[1, 2, AnotherName[3, 4]])
```

Which would be equivalent to the following:

```
make_result(
    "some::Path", 
    1.convert(), 
    2.convert(), 
    make_result(
        "AnotherName", 
        3.convert(), 
        4.convert()
    )
)
```

where `convert` is some trait that will be implemented for a bunch of types. (`convert` and `make_result` has the same result type).

This is as far as I've come:

```
// Note: u32 is used as an example result type. 
// The real code attempts to create a more complicated object.

trait Foo {
    fn convert(&self) -> u32;
}

fn make_result(name: &str, data: Vec<u32>) -> u32 {
    // This example ignores name and makes a meaningless result
    data.iter().fold(0,|a, &b| a + b)
}


#[macro_export]
macro_rules! mactest {
    ( [ $($inner:expr),* ] ) => {{
        let mut result = Vec::new();
        $(
            // Process each element.
            result.push(mactest!($inner));
        )*
        result
    }};
    ($name:path [ $($inner:tt),* ] ) => {
        make_result(stringify!($name), mactest!([$($inner),*]))
    };
    ($name:ident [ $($inner:tt),* ] ) => {
        make_result(stringify!($name), mactest!([$($inner),*]))
    };
    // Process single value. This is never matched?
    ($x:expr) => {
        $x.convert()
    };
}
```

The first matching branch of the macro is supposed to match each element of a list to either the `path/ident[items]` or the single item `.convert` branch at the end. But the final branch is never reached, with rust complaining `error: expected ident, found '1'` when single items enter the macro, i.e. `mactest!(1)`.

My reasoning as a beginner rust user is that the macro has four patterns: `[expr*]`, `path[tt*]`, `ident[tt*]` and `expr`. When I pass something like 1 into the macro, I don't see why any of the above patterns should match/interfere.

Can someone explain why this doesn't work? Is there a workaround to get the intended result?

Comment: your macro doesn't work in the regular case: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6ce29f2366951025ad4b&version=stable . It complains with "expected one of `.`, `]`, or an operator, found `,`"

Answer (score 0):

macro rules are tried by starting with the first one and going down from there. So if you want to prevent your other rules from triggering in special cases, you need to put the special case rule first.

[Try it out in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=483ac8eef58586c782dc&version=stable)

Comment: Aside from that, the problem is that the outer invocation matches as `:expr`, which prevents the "special case" rules from *ever* matching.  This can't be done except by incremental parsing.

Comment: What confuses me is that, in the case of `mactest(1)`, I don't see how any of the first three rules matches `1`. Those are the special cases, which is why they are at the top. `1` is not an `ident` nor a `path`. To narrow it down, [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dc58b6e911d75f546cb3&version=stable) error message really confuses me. @DK. What does incremental parsing mean in this context?

Comment: @porgarmingduod Bed time for me, but this (among other things) is explained in [TLBoRM](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/).  Short version: the `macro_rules!` parser is *really* dumb, and the fact that `1` isn't an ident *is* the problem.  That specific formulation is *impossible* to get working; see section 2.3.1.

Comment: @DK. Thanks, that is just the kind of resource I needed to shore up my shortcomings about rust macros. Can't believe it never showed up when I was googling various macro stuff.